# How to set matplotlib chart scale so it doesn't change as line grows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

When I run this Python program the x and y axes scale adjusts as more data gets plotted. Is it possible to set a scale to which the chart will be created to and have it not change during excution? I had tried `plt.xlim(0, 30)` and `plt.ylim(0, 1050)` but it made no difference.

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

data = pd.read_csv('csv_data.csv')
x_vals = []
y_vals1 = []
y_vals2 = []

index = count()


def animate(i):
    x = data['x_value']
    y1 = data['total_1']
    y2 = data['total_2']
    x_vals = x[0:i]
    y_vals1 = y1[0:i]
    y_vals2 = y2[0:i]

    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals1, label='Channel 1')
    plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals2, label='Channel 2')

    plt.legend(loc='upper left')

    plt.tight_layout()


ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, frames=len(data.index) -1, interval=100, repeat = False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you put your x_lim and y_lim lines in your animate function after plt. cla()?

Comment: Ah, I had it before that. Once I moved it the chart displayed as I want it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines after `plt.cla`:

```py
plt.xlim(0, 27)
plt.ylim(900, 1050)
```